# Is there a "pause" function in R?

Tags: r

I'm writing a user-defined function that includes a for-loop and would like to pause execution after every iteration. Is there some function that does this, like "pause" in MATLAB?

Comment: You could use `readline` to ask the user to hit `enter` after each iteration, but that's perhaps not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can pause execution by using `Sys.sleep()`. So, to wait for one second: `Sys.sleep(1)`.